# pin activity with button onclick

Tags: html, css

Here is my login panel : http://jsfiddle.net/M87Pm/1/

Here Adding any action to button messing up with my layout. Any ideas?

This is my action on form. when I put this after div container class it is wrong.

`<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">`

Comment: I don't really get what your problem is, from the provided fiddle.

Comment: I think we'll like to see the contents of `checklogin.php` file

Comment: ..or at least the rest of the HTML

Comment: @MightyPork here it is, sorry all. I mess up with links

Comment: @tas9 take a look at this

Comment: Take a better look to your code. You're enclosing the <form> tag between <div> and </div> (lines 1 to 3) and that won't work! And there's a form inside another form.. I don't think that can work.

Comment: @tas9 delete divs and leave form. nothing has changed ;)

Comment: @tas9 http://jsfiddle.net/M87Pm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tags `<form>` and you forgot to close the first.

Try using  `</form>`